# Асинхронное считывание файла в Linux

Tags: linux, io, асинхронность

Я хочу получить следующую функциональность

Открываю файл, вызываю функцию асинхронного чтения и делаю дальше свои дела (т.е. код после вызова этой функции выполняется). Дальше ядро, выполнив чтение файла, записало мне в буффер процесса, из которого я отправил ядру указание на чтение, содержимое файла. Затем ядро отправляет мне сигнал и я обработчиком на этот сигнал, могу работать с желаемым файлом.

Есть ли такие возможности? Какую функцию при этом использовать?

Comment: подозреваю что такой функциональности нет. зато есть mmap(), который гораздо круче. он отражает файл в адресное пространство вашего процесса. после чего вы работаете с ним как с обычной оперативной памятью. блоки файла читаются физически с диска в память по мере необходимости. Что примечательно - пользовательский процесс непосредственно работает с тем же блоками что и ядро и повторного копирования ядро-пользователь после чтения, как с обычными вызовами не происходит

Comment: А если нужна все таки именно такая функциональность, то вы ее легко можете реализовать сами. делаете отдельный поток ввода-вывода, который читает файл и сообщает об этом основному потоку

Comment: Попробуйте именные тр'убы. `mkfifo`,`write` туда, `read` суда.

Comment: @Semerkin не это https://github.com/littledan/linux-aio ли ищите?

Comment: Да, похоже на то, спасибо